# How to create a proxy with apache 2.2?

Tags: apache, tomcat, proxy

I have a web app deployed on Tomcat. So my web is reachable with the url http//localhost:8080/myapp. Tomcat is install on my computer. I've installed Apache 2.2 (xampp) because i want to make a proxy. My aim is to build a proxy in order to have the following use case :

`1. http://127.0.0.1:8080/myapp =>` displays my web app(as now)

`2. http://mysuperapp.com/myapp =>` displays my web app ( here the http request is handled by my `http://localhost:8080/myapp` and the navigator always displays url http://mysuperapp.com/myapp).

Here is the configuration i use : 
httpd.conf :

```
...various non-proxy-related modules omitted...
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
LoadModule proxy_html_module modules/mod_proxy_html.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName   mysuperapp.com
   ProxyPass        / http://localhost:8080/
   ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
   ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain localhost mysuperapp.com
   ProxyPreserveHost On
</VirtualHost>
```

When i try the url mysuperapp.com/myapp i cannot see my webapp. Is it something wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that mysuperapp.com correctly resolves to the computer that apache is running on? Just by mentioning a server name in apache's config, doesn't make it accessible under that name.

Is Apache running on the same computer as tomcat? If not, you can't use `http://localhost:8080/` but will have to give the name your tomcat is accessible to Apache under (e.g. log in to the Apache-running computer and access your webapp from a browser there. If it's a headless server, use lynx or w3m - those are shell-based (text-mode) browsers.

If it's not any of these reasons, please specify "I cannot see my webapp" further: What can you see instead?

**Edit**: I've seen you've made some (moderator-rejected) edits to this answer: You should add these comments as "comments" below this answer.

From those edits I have the feeling that you'll have to work on the DNS side - e.g. you'll need to figure out how to make your Apache available under mysuperapp.com: So far you have configured it to reply correctly *if* it has been reached under that domain name, but it seems that the general name resolution does not point to it: Try `ping mysuperapp.com`. If that doesn't resolve to the IP-address of your Apache, you don't need to worry about anything else.